# CSS media queries (mobile, tablets, and screens)

Tags: media-queries

I'm trying to make the move to being a **Responsive developer** (instead of a fixed one). I've been trying to understand media queries as of late and having some confusion. The test is simple:

I want to change the body background color to red for mobile, yellow for tablets, green for wide screens. The following code demonstrates this (for the most part). The issue I'm having is when the width drops below 480px (30em's), the background reverts back to its default `css` (background turns red to white). Now.., my small mind tells me "ohh I'll just make a

```
     @media only screen and (min-width:1em) { body { background:red;} }
```

... that will fix the problem!"

This however seems wrong and unintuitive. Does anyone know the proper way to achieve this simple task?

```
/*
==========================================================================
 MOBILE (min-width 480px)
========================================================================== */
   @media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {

    body { background:red; font-size:.75em; }

}


/* 
==========================================================================
 TABLETS (min-width 768px)
========================================================================== */
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {

body { background:yellow;  font-size:.85em; }

}

/* 
==========================================================================
 SCREENS (min-width 1140px)
========================================================================== */
@media only screen and (min-width: 71.25em) {

body { background:green;  font-size:1em; }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I'll revert the whole CSS into a `max-width`. Something like `max-width: XX` is a smartphone, `max-width: YY` is a tablet, else is a screen. So, it'll turn into something like this:

```
body { background:green;  font-size:1em; }  

@media only screen and (max-width: 71.25em) {
  body { background:yellow;  font-size:.85em; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 48em) {
  body { background:red; font-size:.75em; }
}
```

Comment: I did that initially and at first the background stayed green no matter which browser size! The effect only worked after I actually "reverted" the entire css code, meaning at first I had it laid out in this screen order "mobile, tablet, screen". The effect only began to work when I switched it over to media "screen, tablet, mobile". I didn't think order counted whenever using media queries for some reason (but i guess it does).

Comment: FYI, `max-width` goes against proper "mobile first" `RWD`.  using only `min-width`, you wont need a breakpoint for your first styles, those will cover the entire site, make that one `red`.  then for your next breakpoint, add the media query (making sure it comes after your main styles, then add your `@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {`  make that one yellow, etc..  Then, try to think of all your media queries as "overrides", in succession.